# Connect APM 2.6 to Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi

Earlier, I worked with APM 2.6 with Raspberry Pi B+, Raspberry Pi A+ and all works fine.

Now I try to connect APM 2.6 to Raspberry Pi 3 and Raspberry Pi Zero and I obtained the next problem:

1. I tried to connect with **USB port** and the command

   ```
   sudo mavproxy.py **--master=/dev/ttyACM0** --baudrate=115200 --out=127.0.0.1:5005 --cmd="wp load mission.txt"
   ```
2. I tried to connect with **telem port** and the command

   ```
   sudo mavproxy.py **--master=/dev/ttyAMA0** --baudrate=57600 --out=127.0.0.1:5005 --cmd="wp load mission.txt"
   ```

   and

   ```
   sudo mavproxy.py **--master=/dev/ttyS0** --baudrate=57600 --out=127.0.0.1:5005 --cmd="wp load mission.txt"
   ```

I always see the next result:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/f1/go $ sudo mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyACM0
--baudrate=115200 --out=127.0.0.1:5005 --cmd="wp load mission.txt"

Connect /dev/ttyACM0 source_system=255

**Loaded 5 waypoints from mission.txt**

Log Directory:

Telemetry log: mav.tlog

MAV> Waiting for heartbeat from /dev/ttyACM0
```

So, MAVProxy writes, that waypoints are loaded, but, when I check it using *Mission Plans* I can't see points. It writes that points are loaded, but they are not.

Help me please to find the solution.